# request all pages in api call

Tags: api, request, postman

So my problem is pretty niche so I'm not sure it will have an answer from the community, but I guess it's worth a try cause I'm hitting a wall. I am trying to call an 8x8 api and getting results, but for some reason. I'm only getting a portion of what should be there. I have these variables X-Page: 9
X-Total-Pages: 38
X-Total-Elements: 37463
and my url is like this
`"https://api.8x8.com/analytics/cc/v5/historical-metrics/3511365/data?page=9&size=1000"` but when I switch it to page=10 I immediately get this error
`"Bad request: Field 'page' must be greater than or equal to 0 and less than the total number of pages, which is 0 for this request"`

It doesn't seem to make sense because based on the variables I should have 38 total pages to work with. I've been trying to search but I haven't seen anyone else have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue I'm having is relative to the report I'm trying to pull. Cause the other reports I ran worked. So I don't think it's a problem with my code or postman at all, seems like 8x8 issue. I opened a ticket to investigate.